# Aggregate Sparse Vectors in column in groupby operation PySpark

Tags: python, apache-spark, machine-learning, pyspark

Problem: **I am trying to combine Sparse Vectors into one per id (it should be an aggregation result after grouping rows by id).**

The origin DataFrame I am operating with (and which I applied transform methods on) looks like this:

*Input*:

```
+---+-------+--------+--------+
| id|   col1|    col2|    col3|
+---+-------+--------+--------+
|  1|  [Red]|  [John]|  [Male]|
|  1| [Blue]| [Alice]|[Female]|
|  1|[Green]|[Celine]|  [Male]|
|  2|  [Red]|   [Bob]|  [Male]|
|  1|  [Red]|  [John]|  [Male]|
|  2|[Green]| [Alice]|[Female]|
+---+-------+--------+--------+
```

What've done so far are two transformations:

In first step I used the **`CountVectorizer`** to get feature vectors per columns per row, output:

```
+---+-------------+-------------+-------------+
|id |vectors1     |vectors2     |vectors3     |
+---+-------------+-------------+-------------+
|1  |(3,[0],[1.0])|(4,[1],[1.0])|(2,[0],[1.0])|
|1  |(3,[2],[1.0])|(4,[0],[1.0])|(2,[1],[1.0])|
|1  |(3,[1],[1.0])|(4,[2],[1.0])|(2,[0],[1.0])|
|2  |(3,[0],[1.0])|(4,[3],[1.0])|(2,[0],[1.0])|
|1  |(3,[0],[1.0])|(4,[1],[1.0])|(2,[0],[1.0])|
|2  |(3,[1],[1.0])|(4,[0],[1.0])|(2,[1],[1.0])|
+---+-------------+-------------+-------------+
```

In second step (basing on previous output), I did use `VectorAssembler` to assembly all these columns into one column named **features**:

```
+---+-------------------------+
|id |features                 |
+---+-------------------------+
|1  |(9,[0,4,7],[1.0,1.0,1.0])|
|1  |(9,[2,3,8],[1.0,1.0,1.0])|
|1  |(9,[1,5,7],[1.0,1.0,1.0])|
|2  |(9,[0,6,7],[1.0,1.0,1.0])|
|1  |(9,[0,4,7],[1.0,1.0,1.0])|
|2  |(9,[1,3,8],[1.0,1.0,1.0])|
+---+-------------------------+
```

**Expected Solution/Output/DataFrame**: What I am trying to achieve is to figure out the groupby operation on id followed by some particular aggregation function that can transform the second output (or maybe somehow first output) into this:

```
+--+-------------------------------------------------------+
|id|features                                               |
+--+-------------------------------------------------------+
|1 |(9,[0,1,2,3,4,5,7,8],[1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0])|
|2 |            (9,[0,1,3,6,7,8],[1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0])|
+--+-------------------------------------------------------+
```

I might be wrong but I am looking most probably for something that can sum all the Sparse Vectors, and combine their internal arrays only...

*also what I am looking for but as an option is to have the possibility in that agg function of assuming the number of occurrences of particular features from the arrays, so alternatively the features columns can be converted to this:

```
+--+-------------------------------------------------------+
|id|features                                               |
+--+-------------------------------------------------------+
|1 |(9,[0,1,2,3,4,5,7,8],[2.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,2.0,1.0,3.0,1.0])| # 0: 2 times, 4: 2 times, 7: 3 times
|2 |            (9,[0,1,3,6,7,8],[1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0])|
+--+-------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Plese read the description of the [tag:ml] tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had a very similar problem, and just found a horrible solution using UDF.

Starting with the sample you provided:

```
from pyspark.ml.linalg import SparseVector, DenseVector
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
df = sc.parallelize([
    (1, SparseVector(9,[0,4,7],[1.0,1.0,1.0])),
    (1, SparseVector(9,[2,3,8],[1.0,1.0,1.0])),
    (1, SparseVector(9,[1,5,7],[1.0,1.0,1.0])),
    (2, SparseVector(9,[0,6,7],[1.0,1.0,1.0])),
    (1, SparseVector(9,[0,4,7],[1.0,1.0,1.0])),
    (2, SparseVector(9,[1,3,8],[1.0,1.0,1.0])),
]).toDF(["id", "features"])
```

I created this UDF to add vectors:

```
from pyspark.ml.linalg import Vectors, VectorUDT
import numpy as np

@F.udf(returnType=VectorUDT())
def elementwise_sum(vectors):
    res = None
    for vec in vectors:
        if res is None:
            res = vec
        else:
            res = np.add(vec,res)
    return SparseVector(len(res),{k: v for k,v in enumerate(res) if v != 0})
```

With this you will be able to agg the vectors and return a resulting vector

```
df = df.groupBy('id').agg(elementwise_sum(F.collect_list('features')).alias('features'))
df.show(10,False)

+---+-------------------------------------------------------+
|id |features_raw                                           |
+---+-------------------------------------------------------+
|1  |(9,[0,1,2,3,4,5,7,8],[2.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,2.0,1.0,3.0,1.0])|
|2  |(9,[0,1,3,6,7,8],[1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0])            |
+---+-------------------------------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 1):

Although the solution of @Maviles works, it is horribly slow for sparse vectors with a large size. It first converts it to dense (numpy) arrays, and aggregates them normally. This ignores the fact that the vectors are sparse. The following implementation will respect the sparse nature of the vectors:

```py
from pyspark.ml.linalg import SparseVector


def sparse_to_dict(sparse: SparseVector):
    return dict(zip(sparse.indices, sparse.values))


def agg_sparse(x: SparseVector, y: SparseVector):
    if x.size != y.size:
        raise ValueError("Dimensions of sparse vectors must match.")
    x_dict, y_dict = sparse_to_dict(x), sparse_to_dict(y)
    merged = {k: x_dict.get(k, 0) + y_dict.get(k, 0) for k in set(x_dict) | set(y_dict)}
    return SparseVector(x.size, merged)
```

I have two vectors of size 262144: `a` and `b`. Then if we time the aggregation:

```py
import timeit


timeit.timeit(lambda : agg_sparse(a, b), number=10)
# 0.005741347999901336 seconds

timeit.timeit(lambda : np.add(a, b), number=10)
# 23.33203807200016 seconds
```

This shows that using `np.add` is incredibly slow for large sparse vectors.